# How do I test CSV download in capybara and poltergeist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I need to be able to test the contents of a CSV file that my Rails application is returning.

In my controller, the code looks like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
  format.csv do
    if current_user.has_rights?
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=info.csv'    
      send_data generate_csv_file
    else
      send_data "Access denied"
    end
  end
end
```

And this code works-- if I visit that URL with the appropriate rights, then the CSV file is downloaded.  However, I can't seem to get any kind of appropriate test working with Poltergeist and Capybara.

If I do the following, [following the response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357563/how-to-test-send-data-in-rspec-or-what-should-i-be-testing-for-in-this-case):

```
describe DashboardsController do
  context "when format is csv" do
    render_views
    let(:csv_string)  { get_csv_headers }
    let(:csv_options) { {filename: "report.csv", disposition: 'attachment', type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present'} }
    let (:csv_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:csv_user)}
    before do
      sign_in csv_user
    end


    it "should return a csv attachment" do
#      @controller.should_receive(:send_data).with("#{csv_string.join(',')}", csv_options).
#        and_return { @controller.render nothing: true } # to prevent a 'missing template' error
      get :index, format: :csv
      puts response.headers
      puts response.body
    end
  end
end
```

The header that's reported via that puts:

```
{"Location"=>"http://test.host/", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

which is clearly wrong.  What can I do to get the response for a csv format be csv within the context of the test?  (please note that I've already included `render_views`, [as suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640421/rspec-test-csv-file-download)).

Answer (score 3):

I'm suffering through the same issue right now. This might help you. => http://sponsorpay.github.io/blog/2012/11/29/capybara-poltergeist-and-csv-downloads/

This may also be relevant. => [Downloading file to specific folder using Capybara and Poltergeist driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739423/downloading-file-to-specific-folder-using-capybara-and-poltergeist-driver)

Comment: An answer on this website should include substance, not just links (which are prone to becoming invalid). If you want to provide just links you should do so in a comment on the question.

Comment: and the reason being... that the link becomes invalid (like it is now) so people like me who come looking for the same solution can't get a solution anymore :(

Comment: First link is available on the Wayback Machine. Before it went down entirely, it redirected to a page mirrored here: http://web.archive.org/web/20141004140513/http://it.fyber.com:80/blog/2012/11/29/capybara-poltergeist-and-csv-downloads